# Create partitioned table with date suffix in bigquery using SQL or web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create such table:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable
(SELECT columns, columns, date_col)
PARTITIONED BY date_col
```

And I want it to be date partitioned with the date in table suffix: sometable$date_partition

I read the docs, but can't complete this neither with web UI nor with SQL.

The web UI shows such error "Missing argument for parameter DATE."

```
My table name is "daily_export_${DATE}"
My partitioning column isn't blank, it's date_col.
```

Can I have a simple example, please?

Comment: Which doc are you referring to that mentions the "${DATE}" syntax? BTW sometable$date_partition is a table name with a partition decorator to address a partition in a table. You can't create a table with name "sometable$20200101". You can create a table with name "sometable" and a partition "20200101" in the table.

Comment: I think you are mixing sharded tables with partitioned tables. Can you take a look at this document and try to explain a little bit more what are you trying to do? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_compare

Comment: Yes, I mixed these, thanks for info.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

- `PARTITION BY` goes earlier
- The query needs to parse the table suffix into a `DATE` type.

For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.so
PARTITION BY date_from_table_name
AS
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _table_suffix) date_from_table_name, event_timestamp, event_name, items  
FROM `bingo-blast-174dd.analytics_151321511.events_*`
WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20200530' AND '20200531'
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard), `BigQuery` implements two different concepts: **sharded tables** and **partitioned tables**

The first one (sharded tables) is a way of dividing a whole table into many tables with a date suffix. You can query those tables individually or using wildcards. For example, instead of creating a single table named *events*, you can create many tables named *events_20200101*, *events_20200102*, [...] 

When you do that, you are able to query any of those tables individually or you can query all of them by running some query like `select * from events_*`

The second concept (partitioned tables) is an approach to fragment your table in smaller pieces in order to improve the performance and reduce costs when querying data. Partitioned tables can be based on some column of your table or even on the ingestion time. When you table is partitioned by ingestion time you can access a pseudo column named `_PARTITIONTIME`

When comparing both approaches, the documentation says:

> Date/timestamp partitioned tables perform better than tables sharded
>   by date. When you create date-named tables, BigQuery must maintain a
>   copy of the schema and metadata for each date-named table. Also, when
>   date-named tables are used, BigQuery might be required to verify
>   permissions for each queried table. This practice also adds to query
>   overhead and impacts query performance. The recommended best practice
>   is to use date/timestamp partitioned tables instead of date-sharded
>   tables.

In your case, you basically need to create a partitioned table without a date in its name.