# How to set a custom partition expiration in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have a dataset for which the `Default table expiration` is `7 days`. I want **only one** of the tables within this dataset **to never expire**.

I found the following `bq` command : `bq update --time_partitioning_expiration 0 --time_partitioning_type DAY project-name:dataset-name.table_name`

The problem is my tables have a partitionning suffix so they're named like this example :
`REF_PRICE_20210921`, `REF_PRICE_20210922`, etc... so the table name *per se* is `REF_PRICE_`.

I can't seem to apply the `bq` command on this partitionned table. As I get an error  `BigQuery error in update operation: Not found: Table project-name:dataset-name.REF_PRICE_` but it does exist. What am I doing/understanding wrong?

EDIT : My tables are not "partitionned" but sharded; they are **wildcard tables**, and so separate. It is not possible to set an expiration date for those tables apparently, unless it's done on each one individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried suffixing the table name with `*` like `REF_PRICE_*` ?
Moreover you should read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62196936/7642411) because you might have created sharded tables while you wanted partitioned one.

Comment: Yeah I have tried with the wildcard `*` and it doesn't work. I think you are right, my tables are not partitionned, but sharded. See [Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference)